# SIGTRAP when freeing a three dimensional array in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc, free

I am trying to free a three dimensional pointer array representing a bmp image and whle it compiles ok I get SIGTRAP signals in gdb when debugging. My error message is

> warning: HEAP[bmpsample.exe]:
>   warning: Heap block at 0061FFB8 modified at 0061FFCC past requested size of c.
>   Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/ breakpoint trap. 0x7787704e5 in ntdll!TpWaitForAlpcCompletion()
>   from ntdll.dll

The error occurs when I free the array after loading in the values from the bmp file. My code is as follows.

Allocation:

```
int ***alloc3D(int xlen, int ylen, int zlen) {
int i, j, ***array;
if ((array = malloc(xlen*sizeof(int**)))==NULL) {
    perror("Error in first assignment of 3D malloc\n");
}
// Allocate pointers for each row
for (i = 0; i < xlen; i++) {
    if ((array[i] = malloc(ylen*sizeof(int*)))==NULL){
        perror("Error in second assignment of 3D malloc\n");
    }
    // Allocate pointer for each column in the row
    for (j=0; j < ylen; j++) {
        if((array[i][j] = malloc(zlen*sizeof(int)))==NULL) {
            perror("Error in third assignment of 3D malloc\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Filling the array

```
int ***readBitmap(FILE *inFile, BmpImageInfo info, int*** array) {
    // Pixels consist of unsigned char values red, green and blue
Rgb *pixel = malloc( sizeof(Rgb) );
int read, j, i;
for( j=0; j<info.height; j++ ) {
    read = 0;
    for( i=0; i<info.width; i++ ) {
        if( fread(&pixel, 1, sizeof(Rgb), inFile) != sizeof(Rgb) ) {
                printf( "Error reading pixel!\n" );
        }
        array[j][i][1] = (int)(pixel->red);
        array[j][i][2] = (int)(pixel->green);
        array[j][i][3] = (int)(pixel->blue);
        read += sizeof(Rgb);
    }

    if ( read % 4 != 0 ) {
        read = 4 - (read%4);
        printf( "Padding: %d bytes\n", read );
        fread( pixel, read, 1, inFile );
    }
}
free(pixel);

return array;
```

}

Deallocation

```
void dealloc3D(int*** arr3D,int l,int m)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
                free(arr3D[i][j]);
        }
        free(arr3D[i]);
    }
    free(arr3D);
}
```

I suscpect that the problem lies in casting the RGB values from unsigned char to int, but I see no other way of doing it. If I simply assign integer values to the alloced array there is no problem with freeing them.

Comment: Did you learn to correctly use `gdb`? Did you ask for the backtrace  (using the `bt` command of `gdb`) when the `SIGTRAP` occur? Did you compile your code with `gcc -Wall -g` ?

Comment: You are corrupting memory.  Change `fread(&pixel, 1, sizeof(Rgb), inFile)` to `fread(pixel, 1, sizeof(*pixel), inFile)` and `read += sizeof(Rgb);` to `read += sizeof(*pixel);`.  That way when and/or if the type of `pixel` changes there will be fewer things to change in your code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am compiling with both `-Wall` and `-g` without errors and bt full shows me that `dealloc3D` is called with the correct address to the array and the correct height and width. I am however very new to GDB and I only know the most basic controls.

Comment: @JimR Thank you for the advice, changing &pixel to pixel did not help sadly. I should also mention that images are read correctly to the array (checked with Matlab).

Comment: I am such an idiot. I am starting my indices from 1 when assigning the color values. The only reason my program gives a readable output is because I am doing the exactly same thing in a later function that converts the image to grayscale, which led me to believe that error had to be found in the deallocation. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the first `fread` statement

```
fread(&pixel, 1, sizeof(Rgb), inFile)
```

which is reading into the pointer `pixel`, not into what `pixel` is pointing to. After that, any use of `pixel` is likely to corrupt the heap (or something else).

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented the changes, but I still get the same error messages, either
`warning: HEAP[BMPSample.exe]: 
warning: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00940000, 00941C80 )`

or

`warning: HEAP[BMPSample.exe]: 
warning: Heap block at 00941C78 modified at 00941C8C past requested size of c`

Comment: Another potential problem is the indexing in `array[j][i][3]`. Depending on what the `Rgb` type looks like, perhaps you should use index 0, 1, and 2 instead of 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: Yes, thank you Bo. I just realized this and changed it and now it works flawlessly. I blame it on being far too used to Matlab indexing.